# In an allegation about attractiveness, is 'averageness' in context?

Tags: grammaticality

Please mind that I denounce and reject the stance of this quote; I ask only about English here.

> But what is our idea of beauty – what makes beautiful people? The report’s authors say
>   there appear to be a few features that characterize physically attractive faces: bilateral symmetry, **averageness**, and secondary sexual characteristics. Attractive faces are
>   more symmetrical than unattractive faces.
>   ..(Source: ‘Beauty and intelligence’ by Brian Page, Mensa Magazine, September 2004)

Source: p 88, *Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*, Mark Shepherd

Which defintion of [average](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/average) as an adjective, coheres with the meaning of the noun? I'm confused by the juxtaposition of (what is contended as) 'beautiful people' and **averageness**.

Answer (score 1):

It's adjective definition 1.2 from your link:

> Having qualities that are seen as typical of a particular person, group, or thing

Your confusion is quite understandable, since in the context of describing appearance, *average* usually means *unremarkable, ordinary or plain; neither ugly nor beautiful*.

But the authors use *average* in the context of discussing psychological motivations rather than qualitative subjective descriptions. People naturally prefer things which are normal; that which is typical of a particular group tends to be preferred over that which is abnormal. Note also that the definition specifies *seen as*, indicating that "averageness" depends on perceptions rather than objective fact, which is very relevant to the usage in question.

This is why *average* (in the sense of *representing the prototypical qualities* and not *plain or unremarkable*) is used here. Adding the *-ness* suffix serves to distance the usage from the common appearance-related meaning. It would certainly be nonsensical to claim that someone not particularly good looking was beautiful.

Comment: "Averageness" could also be a nod to being more relatable.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would say that the meaning of "average" is almost *statistical*.

As you point out, it's clear from the context that the author isn't talking about "average" facial features in the sense of facial features of average beauty. The mention of symmetry in the same sentence makes me think that the author means an "average" face in the sense of being unextreme; nose neither too long nor too short, ears neither too large nor too small, lips neither too thin nor to broad, and so on.

In the link you gave in your question, that would make it a mix of meanings 1, 1.1 and 1.2.